# Insert from select failing with strange error

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have an after insert trigger which will get data from a select, this is returning error

Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 SQL1.sql 1 1

Have tried running this manually - same result

```
  INSERT INTO stkmonth (MONTH, YEAR, LOCATION, ATTRIB1, ATTRIB2, ATTRIB3, QTY_ONHAND, COST)
    VALUES ((SELECT
      MONTH(new.TRANS_DATE) AS month,
      YEAR(new.TRANS_DATE) AS year,
      new.location AS location, stock.ATTRIB1, stock.ATTRIB2, stock.ATTRIB3,
      SUM(stocklvl.QTY_ONHAND) AS qty_onhand,
      SUM(stocklvl.QTY_ONHAND * stocklvl.AVG_COST) AS cost
    FROM sales INNER JOIN stocklvl ON sales.ISC_CODE = stocklvl.ISC_CODE
    INNER JOIN stock ON sales.ISC_CODE = stock.ISC_CODE WHERE stock.ISC_CODE = new.isc_code GROUP BY stocklvl.ISC_CODE))
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    qty_onhand = qty_onhand - new.qty, cost = (new.qty * new.cost);
```

I would expect this to work but it seems to think there is a column error.
Note this may at times not find anything to select this is OK, in this case I would want it to move on, could the empty record set be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference: [MySQL Insert...Select Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-select.html)

- In `Insert..Select`, don't use `VALUES` keyword.
- Don't wrap select statement in brackets.

```
INSERT INTO stkmonth (MONTH, YEAR, LOCATION, ATTRIB1, ATTRIB2, ATTRIB3, QTY_ONHAND, COST)
SELECT 
    MONTH(new.TRANS_DATE) AS MONTH, 
    YEAR(new.TRANS_DATE) AS YEAR,
    new.location AS location, 
    stock.ATTRIB1, 
    stock.ATTRIB2, 
    stock.ATTRIB3, 
    SUM(stocklvl.QTY_ONHAND) AS qty_onhand, 
    SUM(stocklvl.QTY_ONHAND * stocklvl.AVG_COST) AS cost
FROM sales
INNER JOIN stocklvl ON sales.ISC_CODE = stocklvl.ISC_CODE
INNER JOIN stock ON sales.ISC_CODE = stock.ISC_CODE
WHERE stock.ISC_CODE = new.isc_code
GROUP BY stocklvl.ISC_CODE
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE qty_onhand = qty_onhand - new.qty, cost = (new.qty * new.cost);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it was driving me crazy :)